# CodeIgniter phpMyAdmin - Inserting into table with a space in the name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->insert('Table One',$data);
```

This would error. And showing the equivalent sql, insert into.

```
INSERT INTO `Table` One (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('----', '------')
```

Is there any way to insert?

Maybe the use of a wildcard perhaps? or any special character to substitute space for phpmyadmin to udnerstand? or is it phpmyadmin's fault?

Comment: Have you tried $this->db->insert('Table One', $data, false); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the active record library doesn't support table names with space in.  I looked into the core files and the `insert()` function calls the `protect_identifiers` function on the table name and in system/database/DB_driver.php there is the following code

```
// If the item has an alias declaration we remove it and set it aside.
// Basically we remove everything to the right of the first space
$alias = '';
if (strpos($item, ' ') !== FALSE)
{
    $alias = strstr($item, " ");
    $item = substr($item, 0, - strlen($alias));
}
```

So everything after the first space is removed.  So it looks like your only options are to do the query like

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO `Table One` ...');
```

Or to remove spaces in your table names

Sorry.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space in your table name, you need to quote the full name:

```
INSERT INTO `Table One` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('----', '------')
```

Comment: That is not the problem. As i wrote it. that was only the conversion or how phpmyadmin took my line of code above.

where i wrote the table name as 'health risk'

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue when doing an update call

```
$this->myBaseTable = "my table";
$this->db->update($this->myBaseTable); //errors
```

It seems to work fine if you added the ticks into the table declaration ie

```
$this->myBaseTable = "`my table`";
```